# How to show animation within Progress Dialog eliminating its Title and Message space?

Tags: android, animation, progressdialog

I an trying to make a Progress Dialog in which an animation sequence is shown, i achieved this but I am not able to eliminate the blank space shown in dialog while running. I want that only the loading circle is to be shown as dialog. Below is my code to show my progress dialog.  ***mytital*** is my animation xml file.

```
private void showDialog() {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);    
         dialog.setCancelable(true);    
         dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
         dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mytital));
         dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help,if you are using AsynTask...

onPreExecute()

```
    LinearLayout  progressLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    progressLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    addContentView(progressLayout,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    progressbar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());
    progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    progressLayout.addView(progressbar);
```

and onPostExecute()

```
progressLayout.removeView(progressbar);
progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: From this you can get "the loading circle" as you want

Comment: Thanks mitB, it works,,but it shows my loading circle only,it doesn't look like a progress dialog...What i want is to show this loader as my progress dialog!!

Comment: Than Do you want Loading Circle with Message "Please wait..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Than you can use this.. :)

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);
 dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
 dialog.show();
```

To dissmis...

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

accept the answer if it works :)